# Unable to add a group as a owner to another group in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

We want to add admin group as a owner to all other groups. When we tried to add via powershell command we got below error

['Group' is invalid for the 'owners' reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I24Jj.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far, the users of stackoverflow might be able to help you if you provide more context and examples.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's not support to add a group as a owner to all other groups currently.

You could use [Get-AzureADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0) to get a list of the group member and then foreach them to add all the members as owners of other groups.

An example:

```
$adgms = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "{objectId of the admin group}" -All $true
foreach($adgm in $adgms){
    Add-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId "{objectId of the target group}" -RefObjectId $adgm.ObjectId
}
```